# jasmine toHaveBeenCalledWith partial matching

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

With Jasmine, I could spy on methods and figure out the arguments. I want to be able to call `toHaveBeenCalledWith(something, anything)`.

Let's say I want to spy on a method `.on(event, callback)`. All I care about is if the `event` is listened to rather than what the actual callback identity is. Is it possible to do this without writing a custom matcher? I don't see one.

Comment: Similar question for jest is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337116/loose-match-one-value-in-jest-tohavebeencalledwith/67193668#67193668

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Try

```
toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Object), jasmine.any(Function))
```

Comment: Can also care even less and use `jasmine.anything()` if the type doesn't matter

Answer (score 65):

Jasmine 2:

```
 expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
    bar: "baz"
  }));
```

https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html#.objectContaining

Comment: This is a better answer and it applies to `jest` too.

Comment: Updated link: https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html#.objectContaining

Comment: It's only a partial check on the first argument and not a partial check on multiple arguments.

Answer (score 27):

If you wish to test for specific things, you can do something like:

```
expect(mockSomething.someMethod.mostRecentCall.args[0].pool.maxSockets).toEqual(50);
```

The syntax in Jasmine 2 is now:

```
mockSomething.someMethod.calls.mostRecent().args[0]
```

Comment: Useful for additional optional arguments.  Note the syntax in Jasmine 2 is now `mockSomething.someMethod.calls.mostRecent().args[0]`

Comment: let spy = spyOn(nameService, 'getName').and.returnValue(Observable.of('Ali'));
nameService.getName('Henry');
expect(spy.calls.all()[0].args[0]).toEqual('Henry');

Comment: In my case I am looking to do a partial match on a long string so expanding oomer's example;  nameService.getNameFromQuestion('The Tutor King who is also a song is Henry');  const longString = spy.calls.mostRecent().arg[0] as string;  expect(longString.search('Henry')).toBeGreaterThanEqualTo(0);