# Loose match one value in jest.toHaveBeenCalledWith

Tags: jestjs

I have an analytics tracker that will only call after 1 second and with an object where the `intervalInMilliseconds` (duration) value is **not** deterministic.

How can I use `jest.toHaveBeenCalledWith` to test the object?

```js
 test('pageStats - publicationPage (will wait 1000ms)', done => {
  const track = jest.fn()

  const expected = new PayloadTiming({
    category: 'PublicationPage',
    action: 'PublicationPage',
    name: 'n/a',
    label: '7',
    intervalInMilliseconds: 1000 // or around
  })

  mockInstance.viewState.layoutMode = PSPDFKit.LayoutMode.SINGLE
  const sendPageStats = pageStats({
    instance: mockInstance,
    track,
    remoteId: nappConfig.remoteId
  })

  mockInstance.addEventListener('viewState.currentPageIndex.change', sendPageStats)

  setTimeout(() => {
    mockInstance.fire('viewState.currentPageIndex.change', 2)

    expect(track).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(track).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

    done()
  }, 1000)

  expect(track).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

`expect(track).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)` fails with:

```
Expected mock function to have been called with:
      {"action": "PublicationPage", "category": "PublicationPage", "intervalInMilliseconds": 1000, "label": "7", "name": "n/a"}
    as argument 1, but it was called with
      {"action": "PublicationPage", "category": "PublicationPage", "intervalInMilliseconds": 1001, "label": "7", "name": "n/a"}
```

I have looked at [jest-extended](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended)
but I do not see anything useful for my use-case.

**EDIT:** I want to highlight that all of the answers here are very useful and you can pick whichever suit your use-case. Thank you all - these answers are great!

Answer (score 308, accepted):

This can be done with asymmetric matchers (introduced in Jest 18)

```js
expect(track).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  expect.objectContaining({
   "action": "PublicationPage", 
   "category": "PublicationPage", 
   "label": "7",
   "name": "n/a"
  })
)
```

If you use `jest-extended` you can do something like

```js
expect(track).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  expect.objectContaining({
   "action": "PublicationPage", 
   "category": "PublicationPage", 
   "label": "7",
   "name": "n/a",
   "intervalInMilliseconds": expect.toBeWithin(999, 1002)
  })
)
```

Answer (score 50):

You can access the expected object for a better assertion using `track.mock.calls[0][0]` (the first `[0]` is the invocation number, and the second `[0]` is the argument number). Then you could use `toMatchObject` to find partially match the object, avoiding the dynamic parameters such as `intervalInMilliseconds`.

Comment: It seems you can use `expect.anything` also: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#expectanything

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r `expect.anything()` does not check what your calling parameter is, it simply checks that they is a parameter.

Answer (score 30):

To re-iterate the [comment by cl0udw4lk3r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337116/loose-match-one-value-in-jest-tohavebeencalledwith#comment100611518_52338611) as I found this the most useful in my scenario:

If you have a method that accepts multiple parameters (not an object) and you only want to match some of these parameters then you can use the [`expect` object](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect).

**Example**

method I want to test:

```js
client.setex(key, ttl, JSON.stringify(obj));
```

I want to ensure the correct values are passed into the `key` and `ttl` but I'm not concerned what the object passed in is. So I set up a spy:

```js
const setexSpy = jest.spyOn(mockClient, "setex");
```

and I can then expect this scenario thus:

```js
expect(setexSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test', 99, expect.anything());
```

You can also use more strongly typed calls using [`expect.any`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectanyconstructor) (`expect.any(Number)`) etc.

Answer (score 21):

My favorite way. You can use the spread operator `...` to expand the object you are checking then overwrite (or add) one or more values.

Here is an example showing how to overwrite the "intervalInMilliseconds" expected value to any Number

```js
const track = jest.fn()

const expected = new PayloadTiming({
    category: 'PublicationPage',
    action: 'PublicationPage',
    name: 'n/a',
    label: '7',
    intervalInMilliseconds: 1000 // or around
  })

expect(track).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  {
    ...expected, 
    intervalInMilliseconds: expect.any(Number)
  })
```

another example showing how to overwrite two values

```js
expect(track).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  {
    ...expected, 
    intervalInMilliseconds: expect.any(Number), 
    category: expect.any(String)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

For later people only want to match parts of the object's inner object.

In my case,

received arguments

```
{
  data: {
    attributes: {
      address: 'test address',
      area: 10000,
      'area-unit': 'square_feet',
      industry: 'agricultural',
      latitude: 30,
      longitude: 104,
      name: 'test',
      timezone: 'Asia/Shanghai',
    },
    relationships: {
      account: { data: { id: '96', type: 'accounts' } },
      users: {
        data: [
          { id: '1180', type: 'users' },
          { id: '1281', type: 'users' },
        ],
      },
    },
    type: 'buildings',
  },
};
```

And what I want to match is `data.attributes`.
So I could use the code below to get the arguments of the called function ( *my function only has one argument, if you want to test the 2nd argument of the first call, it will be `mockFn.mock.calls[0][1]`*)

```
const arg0 = mockFn.mock.calls[0][0];
expect(arg0.data.attributes).toEqual({
      address: 'test address',
      area: 10000,
      'area-unit': 'square_feet',
      industry: 'agricultural',
      latitude: 30,
      longitude: 104,
      name: 'test',
      timezone: 'Asia/Shanghai',
    });
```

I think it's more flexible than `expect.objectContaining(object)` or `.toMatchObject()` for some cases.