# Jest Expected and receive are identical

Tags: jestjs, stenciljs

Is there a reason why Jest would see this as a not identical when both seem exactly the same?

So here is the code I am using to do the test, it's basically just a function that calls for an event emiter, in the event emiter if the date is invalid, I let it as is :

```
  const datepickerComponent: Datepicker = new Datepicker();

  const mockEvent = {
    target: {
      classList: {
        remove: jest.fn(),
        add: jest.fn(),
      },
      value: '01-01-197',
    },
  } as unknown as InputEvent;

  datepickerComponent.onInput(mockEvent);

  const emitMock: jest.Mock = jest.fn();
  datepickerComponent.dsdDatepickerInputChange = { emit: emitMock } as unknown as EventEmitter<dsdDatepickerInputChangeEvent>;

  // when
  datepickerComponent.onInput(mockEvent);

  const dateValue = new Date('197-01-01T00:00:00');

  // then
  expect(emitMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ value: '197-01-01', valueAsDate: dateValue });
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe there is some strange Unicode character hidden in it, like a zero width space? You could try running it through [a Unicode analyzer](https://devina.io/unicode-analyser)

Comment: doesn't seem like thats the case...I tested copy pasted both from the terminal...

Comment: Can you share some of the code, what kind of expect are you using and how are the compared objects being generated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The reason** why you are observing this error is because whilst `Date { NaN }` values look the same, they actually refer to different object instances and cannot be traversed for equality any further, hence the actual error should be the following:

```
Expected: {"value": "197-01-01", "valueAsDate": Date { NaN }}
Received: serializes to the same string
```

(To reproduce this error - create two new dates using `new Date('197-01-01T00:00:00')` and pass them into `.equals()`)

**To get past this error**, all you need to do is to simply refactor your `.toHaveBeenCalledWith` test into the following:

```
const calledWithArg = emitMock.mock.calls[0][0];
expect(JSON.stringify(calledWithArg)).toEqual(JSON.stringify({ value: '197-01-01', valueAsDate: dateValue }));
```

The reason why `.toHaveBeenCalledWith` does not work is because it does not allow us to reshape the argument object before a comparison (in our case we need to *stringify* it), hence we can alternatively extract the argument that the mock was called with via `.mock.calls[0][0]`, *stringify* it and then compare it to the *stringified* version of the expected object.

Answer (score 0):

Reference of `valueAsDate` is different. But [Jest doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-) affirm it uses `.toEqual` for comparison. That means it try to deeply compare two `new Date`. This is a bad idea, you don't control the Date class, and there are probably some moving parts inside.

To loose match a value, you can check this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55569458/7696155